# Converting multiple CSV files to 3D array in Java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I am trying to convert 60 csv files to a multidimensional array with values placed on a "3D:  position based on [file] [row] and [cell]. I am just starting with java, I might be overlooking something simpel, but have been trying to fix this for days. All help is welcome.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GetDataFromCSV.test(GetDataFromCSV.java:30)
   at GetDataFromCSV.main(GetDataFromCSV.java:14)
```

---

the code:

```
1 import java.io.BufferedReader;
2 import java.io.File;
3 import java.io.FileInputStream;
4 import java.io.IOException;
5 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
6 
7 
8 public class GetDataFromCSV {
9 
10  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
11      File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\workspace\\Administratie2\\csv");
12      File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
13      String[][][] fileLineCell = new String[directoryListing.length][][];
14      test(fileLineCell, directoryListing);
15      System.out.println (fileLineCell[0][0][0]);
16  }
17  
18  public static void test(String[][][] fileLineCell, File[] directoryListing) throws IOException{
19      
20      for (int file = 0;  file < directoryListing.length; file++) {
21          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(directoryListing[file]);
22          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
23          String strLine;
24 
25          //Read File Line By Line
26          int line = 0;
27          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
28              String[] splitted = strLine.split(",");
29              for(int cell = 0; cell < splitted.length; cell++){
30                  fileLineCell[file][line][cell] = splitted[cell];
31                  line++;
32              }
33 
34              
35          }
36 
37          //Close the input stream
38          br.close();
39 
40 
41      } 
42      
43      
44      
45  }
46 }
47 
48
```

Comment: String[][][] fileLineCell = new String[directoryListing.length][][];
you didn't initalize properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[][][] fileLineCell = new String[directoryListing.length][][];
```

this line will only initialize the first dimension of the array. so every object in this 3d array is actually a null 2d String array (i.e fileLineCell[index] == null for each 0 <= index < directoryListing.length)
you need to fix the size for the second and third dimesntion as well. if you do not know them you should use some other container (like ArrayList)